# HeidiSQL Not Accepting Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, heidisql

So, I basically have this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NotificationLog(IN `Timestamp` BIGINT, IN UnitID INT, IN Content VARCHAR(50), IN `LEVEL` TINYINT, IN Solved INT, IN Sector TINYINT)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE newId INT;
    INSERT INTO `logs` VALUES (NULL, `Timestamp`, `UnitID`);
    SET newId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO notificationlogs VALUES (newId, Content, `Level`, Solved, Sector);
END;
```

But there's an error, when I run it on the Query tab of *Heidi SQL 10* (which I'm using to manage the DB), it gives me the error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax near " at line 4

Which is the most useless uninformative message ever. I have no idea what's wrong in the syntax because this error tells nothing.

Is there something wrong in the syntax? The docs on MariaDB aren't that helpful for stored procedures with temp variables.

**Edit**: It seems this is a HeidiSQL problem rather than MariaDB, changed the question title.

Comment: Maybe you have some invisible char on line 4, try copy the code from here back and see if it works.

Comment: did that already. But do you know if this is valid in other dbs?

Answer (score 0):

I used HeidiSQL's GUI tool to create the procedure and it generated me the following code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CreateNotificationLog`(
    IN `Timestamp` BIGINT,
    IN `UnitID` INT,
    IN `Content` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `Level` TINYINT,
    IN `Solved` BIT,
    IN `Sector` TINYINT


)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE newId INT;
    INSERT INTO `logs` VALUES (NULL, `Timestamp`, `UnitID`);
    SET newId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO notificationlogs VALUES (newId, Content, `Level`, `Solved`, Sector);
END
```

Though this works, I'd still like to know what was wrong in my handwritten code.

Comment: Perhaps in Heidi SQL the semicolon of the end influences something (`END <> END;`).

Comment: Still gives an error. I'm assuming it's a MariaDB bug.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8c771e678e9fb130c7b3ecadf8e405dd).

Comment: Then maybe it's a HeidiSQL bug? Could you try it on HeidiSQL?